# IN MVC2 how to get telerik gridview data on post method

Tags: post, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, grid

I use Telerik grid. I bind this grid using list of object. When I post the grid data I have not got the list of object value. Please tell me how to get the grid data on post method. Actually I want to save all grid data on one post method.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has several types of grids and several methods to use each grid. Without being more specific or providing code examples it will be difficult to help you. Check out the Telerik Demos. They have an excellent demo site that shows working examples along with a breakdown of the code.

http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx